# Apache static files and handler

Tags: apache

I have web-handler which process requests and respond with generated HTML pages.
But i have also some static files like css and js and want to place it in some subfolder on server. I dont understand how to set up apache config file for this.
My working config is:

```
Alias "/myapp " "C:/Apache22/htdocs/myapp/"
<Directory "C:/Apache22/htdocs/myapp/">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    SetHandler 1c-application
    ManagedApplicationDescriptor "C:/Apache22/htdocs/myapp/default.vrd"
</Directory>
```

When i enter "localhost/myapp" - it's work fine.
But when i enter "localhost/myapp/css/my.css" - apache anyway send requests to my handler application.

How can i set up apache to send requests "/myapp" to my handler and "/myapp/css" to folder "C:/Apache22/htdocs/myapp/css"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by placing all static data in different directory:

```
Alias "/myapp/css" "C:/Apache22/htdocs/myapp_static/css/"
<Directory  "C:/Apache22/htdocs/myapp_static/css/">
     Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```